# Bypass `find_package` in CMake for specific targets?

Tags: c++, cmake, target

Is there a way to have a specific target that is still able to build even if `find_package` fails? For instance, I have a target that just compiles the code documentation and naturally has no hard requirements/dependencies, but cmake won't even finish configuration in case there is a missing dependency.

Comment: find_package does not need to be a fatal error. I mean if you don't have `REQUIRED` that will allow the configure to complete. Now if the dependency is actually needed you would expect to have some type of build error of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you read this part of documentation:

[find_package — CMake 3.23.0-rc2 Documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html#basic-signature)

> Regardless of the mode used, a `<PackageName>_FOUND` variable will be set to indicate whether the package was found. When the package is found, package-specific information may be provided through other variables and [Imported Targets](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html#imported-targets) documented by the package itself. The `QUIET` option disables informational messages, including those indicating that the package cannot be found if it is not `REQUIRED`. The `REQUIRED` option stops processing with an error message if the package cannot be found.
>
> A package-specific list of required components may be listed after the `COMPONENTS` keyword. If any of these components are not able to be satisfied, the package overall is considered to be not found. If the `REQUIRED` option is also present, this is treated as a fatal error, otherwise execution still continues. As a form of shorthand, if the `REQUIRED` option is present, the `COMPONENTS` keyword can be omitted and the required components can be listed directly after `REQUIRED`.
>
> Additional optional components may be listed after `OPTIONAL_COMPONENTS`. If these cannot be satisfied, the package overall can still be considered found, as long as all required components are satisfied.

Note keywords:  `QUIET` `REQUIRED` `OPTIONAL_COMPONENTS`

You can alter behavior of you cmake code by using `<PackageName>_FOUND` to handle failure.